# What exactly is "dwarf star alloy"?

Tags: dc, arrowverse

Ray Palmer's A.T.O.M. suit is said to be made out of "dwarf star alloy". What exactly is this? Is it literally from a dwarf star? Or is it just a fancy name for something else?

Comment: It's also cropped up in Doctor Who (new and old) so it might be a reference within a reference depending on the dates involved.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Yes, it is from a dwarf star

Specifically, this is a reference to the character of the Atom from DC Comics, who created his size-changing suit out of material [from a white dwarf star](http://comicvine.gamespot.com/showcase-34-birth-of-the-atom-battle-of-the-tiny-t/4000-5454/).

[image]

In the show, Palmer gets it from a mine:

> Yep, I just sent the notarized transfer of ownership. Now listen, I
>   want to get a jump on the mining operations immediately. Let me know
>   as soon as the first of the **dwarf star alloy** is extracted.

In either case, the material is literally a piece of a white dwarf star, though in the Arrowverse it would seem to be further underground.

As an aside, a white dwarf star has a density of about 1,000,000,000 kilograms per cubic meter. Assuming that little piece of star Palmer is picking up is 0.1 meters in radius, it should have a mass of about 4,000,000 kilograms, or a weight of about 10 million pounds. Even for a field scientist, Palmer is surprisingly athletic.

Comment: Wow, he can pick up the dwarf star alloy with his bare hands, then points out how dense it is. Are we sure one of Ray doesn't have super strength ;-)

Comment: Science in old comics was fun. For example, apparently “ultraviolet” simply means “very violet.”

Comment: I love how a scientist picks up a METEOR, a radioactive and very hot with his bare hands, and let's not forget that this thing would probably weight hundreds of tons

Comment: @Petersaber - Thousands, probably.

Comment: @Petersaber meteors are not very hot. They've been in space a lot longer than the brief atmospheric re-entry. If you pick them up with bear hands you're more likely to get frostbite.

Comment: @OrangeDog you're right. While they heat up to stupid levels on entry, they cool down very quickly (but not instantly).

Comment: @Petersaber they are cold before they hit the ground and frosted over almost immediately after impact.

Comment: @OrangeDog If you pick them up with bear hands, you're more likely to be savaged by the bear.

Comment: Fun part about real science: A chunk of white dwarf star matter is - mostly carbon - so basically he picks up a chunk of coal. A chunk of core matter, witout the rest of the star compressing it, is - likely going to expand very very quickly.

Comment: @Adwaenyth Because I can't help but giving more science input. If a chunk of white dwarf 10cm across somehow separated from a star, it would have a mass of about 4,000 tons and be composed primarily of carbon and oxygen. If removed from tremendous gravitational pressure, it would expand and chemically react to form carbon monoxide or dioxide, depending on the element ratio. Assuming formation of carbon monoxide, if you teleported such a chunk to the Earth's surface it would release about 16 TJ of chemical energy, about 1/4 of the power of the bomb dropped on Hiroshima.

Comment: @kingledion If it would be core matter at (or close to) core temperature (which it woul have to be since it hasn't expanded yet) it would still be way too hot to be anything but plasma. Yet the gravitational binding energy of that much core matter alone would easily be more than enough to produce a hydrogen bomb like explosion. Don't forget in a star, stellar fusion counteracts gravitational pull. And a stellar core is far less dense than a white dwarf. All that energy compressed there would suddenly be released if that chunk miracolously appeared outside a stellar core.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is actually from a white dwarf star, but Raymond has a shrink ray emitter in his suit to compress, or thread, the actual dwarf star fragment through the exoskin, making the exoskin the armour itself.

Comment: This seems to answer the question, but could you elaborate/add some sources? Spare answers often receive downvotes, whereas the detailed ones tend to get upvoted.